# No "$" or "#" Sign After Logging in Solaris 10 with Putty

Tags: ssh, solaris, putty

This is my environment:

Solaris Version 10; Sun OS Version 5.10 Oracle Version: 11g Enterprise x64 Edition.

When I am getting log on through putty it is giving me this output:

```
login as: ora Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
Last login: Sun Nov 2 10:24:21 2014 from abc
```

It is not showing "`$`" sign or anything.. I can't write on it but cannot execute Linux command or get any output from it. I have even logged in by root password and yet still same. Can I one describe me this to me and guide this matter.

My Oracle Based Database is running on it and I don't want to restart my server. So how can I fixed it and get `$` or `#` ?

Comment: Are you able to SSH to the server from another Solaris box? Do you have physical access to the server? It may be that the SSH daemon on the server has crashed.

Comment: @JosephR...

No, I am not able to SSH to the server from another Solaris Box.
Yes, I have physical access to the server.

If SSH daemon on the server has been crashed. How can I fix it than ??

Comment: Connect a monitor and keyboard and log in to the server locally and try restarting the SSH daemon.

Comment: @JosephR...

I cannot connect monitor to it..
But I have connected it with serial port and this is what it is showing :

Comment: Nov  2 12:04:21 hooradb2 scsi: WARNING: /pci@1f,700000/pci@0/pci@2/pci@0/pci@8/LSILogic,sas@1/sd@3,0 (sd5):
Nov  2 12:04:21 hooradb2        Error for Command: read                    Error Level: Retryable
Nov  2 12:04:21 hooradb2 scsi:  Requested Block: 1632                      Error Block: 1632
Nov  2 12:04:21 hooradb2 scsi:  Vendor: SEAGATE                            Serial Number: 071891XA2J
Nov  2 12:04:21 hooradb2 scsi:  Sense Key: Aborted Command
Nov  2 12:04:21 hooradb2 scsi:  ASC: 0x8 (LUN communication time-out), ASCQ: 0x1, FRU: 0x81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue.

The server was on hang state due to hardware failure.
I let it remained logged in for more than 30 mins & it got the terminal.

But thanks for the suggestions guys !!

Comment: You can accept your own vote as well, and this is what I suggest to do. Good luck.

Comment: haha.. thanks for the suggestion @peterh !!

Comment: My plea. And now, stepping over 15 point of reputation, you can voting up questions or answers, too. An upvote gives 5 or 10 reputation point to its author, so it is a big reward.

Answer (score 2):

The system is telling you there is a faulty disk (or controller/cable/whatever):

```
Nov 2 12:04:21 hooradb2 scsi: Requested Block: 1632 Error Block: 1632 Nov 2 12:04:21 hooradb2 scsi: Vendor: SEAGATE Serial Number: 071891XA2J 
Nov 2 12:04:21 hooradb2 scsi: Vendor: SEAGATE Serial Number: 071891XA2J Nov 2 12:04:21 hooradb2 scsi: Sense Key: Aborted Command Nov 2 12:04:21 hooradb2 scsi: ASC: 0x8 (LUN communication time-out), ASCQ: 0x1, FRU: 0x81
```

There is no point investigating a shell prompt issue while the system hangs. Boot on a alternate media (eg a live CD) and investigate / fix that issue from here. An fsck might be enough but replacing the disk and restoring from backup might be the only way to recover your server.

Comment: hmm..

But the thing is in that case I have to restart the system..
But I dont want to restart the system..

Is there any option for me ?? 
or do I have to restart it to proceed further ??

Comment: Is the system usable beyond not allowing remote login ?

Answer (score 0):

check variable `PS1` :

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
root@debian:/home/mohsen#
```

check your initialization files for modification it.

If you use bash you can use the following escape codes for PS1 variable:

```
      \a     an ASCII bell character (07)
      \d     the date  in  "Weekday  Month  Date"  format
             (e.g., "Tue May 26")
      \e     an ASCII escape character (033)
      \h     the hostname up to the first `.'
      \H     the hostname
      \j     the  number of jobs currently managed by the
             shell
      \l     the basename of the shell's terminal  device
             name
      \n     newline
      \r     carriage return
      \s     the  name  of  the shell, the basename of $0
             (the portion following the final slash)
      \t     the current time in 24-hour HH:MM:SS format
      \T     the current time in 12-hour HH:MM:SS format
      \@     the current time in 12-hour am/pm format
      \u     the username of the current user
      \v     the version of bash (e.g., 2.00)
      \V     the release of bash,  version  +  patchlevel
             (e.g., 2.00.0)
      \w     the current working directory
      \W     the  basename  of the current working direc­
             tory
      \!     the history number of this command
      \#     the command number of this command
      \$     if the effective UID is 0, a #, otherwise  a
             $
      \nnn   the  character  corresponding  to  the octal
             number nnn
      \\     a backslash
      \[     begin a sequence of non-printing characters,
             which could be used to embed a terminal con­
             trol sequence into the prompt
      \]     end a sequence of non-printing characters
```

Comment: Sorry for deleting previous comment..

nothing..

I cannt run any command on it...

Nothing...

Comment: I had all the permissions, I had been connecting to this server for months now...

Infact it is showing same thing even when I am logging in with root !!

Comment: So you can run echo, echo is built-in command of csh, bash, and other shells.

Comment: Its not responding to echo or any other command at all..
Its all blank..

Comment: If echo $PS1 is blank, so $PS1 is empty, if you want to find out you can run coomand or not , run : `find .`

Comment: Sure you can run command.

Comment: I wrote find .
and Its all blank...

Comment: any other suggestions ??